# How to manipulate auto-complete quotes in sublime text 3?

Tags: sublimetext3

I have been using Sublime Text 3 for a few weeks now and am enjoying it for the most part, but for a couple of packages I use (the built in Scala and SublimeHaskell) auto-complete seems to have a bug for quotes. I will type `"` and Sublime will auto-complete it to `""` which is fine, it's what I want. However when I finish typing in the quotes and go to close them with another `"`, Sublime just inserts another `"` without realizing that I am finished with the quote. So I end up with `"some text""`, have to delete the extra `"`, then use the arrow keys to get out of the quotes. This also happens with `'`. Is there something I can do to fix this bug? I would hate to have to use another editor just because of this annoying quirk.

Comment: Are you sure the document doesn't contain an unclosed quote, or a tricky combination of embedded/escaped quotes? What version/build are you using?

Comment: @NoChecksum I am using version 3083. I'm sure it isn't anything that has slipped in, I tested a blank doc with Python syntax and it works fine, with SublimeHaskell or Scala it does not.

Comment: It sounds like a bug with the syntax definitions for those languages? I am using PHP/HTML and a custom Twig definition with no problems on 3083. Might be worth a bug report to the author(s)

Comment: Maybe the default rules have this behavior? I'm in makesfiles which have no suffix, I'm getting this behavior too and it's terribly rude